# HP Elitebook Revolve 810 trackpad not working

Tags: mouse, hp, trackpad

I just installed the newest version of Ubuntu today and the trackpad will click, but will not right click or scroll. I'm fairly new to Linux so any help would be extremely helpful.

Answer (score 0):

You might have some luck altering the options for the trackpad's driver (if it is Synaptics).  Open a terminal, and take a look at the output from the following command

synclient -l

(which gives options and corresponding values for the trackpad if the Synaptics driver is being used).  I have a different machine (MacBook Pro) so my options are probably different from what you need, but for what its worth my value for the VertTwoFingerScroll option is 1, TapButton = 2, and ClickFinger2 = 3.  Not sure if these are the appropriate options, but they may help.
(To set an option, use synclient option=value, for example synclient TapButton=2).